# Using .Contains with List(Of Structures

Tags: vb.net

This code works - I get true, then false

```
Dim listDates As New List(Of Date)
listDates.Add("2022-03-15")
Debug.Print(listDates.Contains("2022-03-15"))
Debug.Print(listDates.Contains("2022-03-16"))
```

If, instead of simple list of dates, I make it a list of structures, is it possible to do a similar test without a loop?

```
Public Structure FileData
    Public FileName As String
    Public FileDate As Date
    Public FileType As String
End Structure

Dim listDates2 As New List(Of FileData)
Dim oneFileData As New FileData
oneFileData.FileDate = "2022-03-15"
listDates2.Add(oneFileData)
Debug.Print(listDates2.Contains("2022-03-15"))
Debug.Print(listDates2.Contains("2022-03-16"))
```

The last 2 lines give me `"Value of type 'string' cannot be converted to 'FileData'` syntax errors which is understandable. But without looping is there a way to look in the FileDate element of the Structures to find a matching element? Something like these pseudocode attempts (which don't work either):

```
Debug.Print(listDates2.FileDate.Contains("2022-03-15"))
Debug.Print(listDates2(FileDate).Contains("2022-03-15"))
```

Comment: The fact that you have successfully used a `String` where a `Date` is expected shows that you have `Option Strict Off`, which regrettably the default. I cannot recommend strongly enough that you set `Option Strict On`, both in the project properties and in the VS options, so it will be `On` by default in future projects. That will force you to take responsibility for using correct data types, including using a `Date` where a `Date` is expected rather than expecting the system to perform an implicit conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Any` extension method is what you want. The `Contains` method basically says "does the list contain an item equal to this" while the `Any` method says "does the list contain an item that satisfies this condition". In your case:

```vb
Debug.Print(listDates2.Any(Function(fd) fd.FileDate = "2022-03-15"))
```

You could also do this:

```vb
Debug.Print(listDates2.Select(Function(fd) fd.FileDate).Contains("2022-03-15"))
```

Answer (score 0):

As John pointed out, I wasn't used Option Strict On.
So the code below uses Option Strict On and also uses John's answer, changed slightly to also meet the Option Strict On requirements.

It now works fine!

```
Public Structure FileData
    Public FileName As String
    Public FileDate As Date
    Public FileType As String
End Structure

Dim listDates2 As New List(Of FileData)
Dim oneFileData As New FileData
oneFileData.FileDate = CDate("2022-03-15")
listDates2.Add(oneFileData)
Debug.Print(CType(listDates2.Any(Function(fd) fd.FileDate = CDate("2022-03-15")), String))
Debug.Print(CType(listDates2.Any(Function(fd) fd.FileDate = CDate("2022-03-16")), String))
```

Comment: If you want to use a hard-coded date then, rather than using `CDate` to convert a `String` literal, just use a `Date` literal: `fd.FileDate = #3/15/2022#`. Note that `Date` literals ALWAYS use US format, i.e. `#M/dd/yyyy#`.

Comment: Also, I would suggest never using `CType(X, String)`. If you want to cast an `Object` reference that already refers to a `String` object then use `CStr`, which is more succinct. If you want to convert something that isn't a `String` already then call its `ToString` method. If you call `Debug.WriteLine` rather than `Debug.Print` then you can just pass an `Object` reference anyway, so no cast or conversion is required. It will call `ToString` implicitly.